# AOSP Android Pie Check if Keyguard is showed

Tags: android, keyguard

Is there a way to detect if the keyguard is displayed on the screen? I know there is the method `isKeyguardLocked()` but it is true for Keyguard Locked (Even if the keyguard is not displayed on the screen)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using isKeyguardLocked() , you can use isKeyguardSecure().

Or

use the method like in the following for if the keyLocked screen is displayed or not,

```
public static boolean isKeyGuardDisplayed(Context context) {
        KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        return manager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
    }
```

Or,

```
public static boolean isKeyGuardDisplayed(Context context) {
        KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        return manager.isDeviceLocked();
    }
```

Hope this answer will help you. :)

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, for Android Pie, the method inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() is deprecated :(

Comment: Yes I know.Then try the same using isDeviceLocked()Also I have edited my answer